# CSS transition not correctly working

Tags: angularjs, css, css-animations

I have a weird problem. I have a CSS flip animation with two images.

The problem is that on the very first transition, the image which is hidden first does not transition well but instead shows instantly at the end of the transition.

However, after the first transition the problem disappears and is working correctly afterwards.

Though the application is written in angularjs, I think this is a CSS problem. How could I solve this?

I've created a fiddle that hopefully explains the problem:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qgxmeddk/)

Html:

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td ng-click="flipCard()">
            <div class="card-container">
                <div class="card" ng-class="{'flipped': !deckVisible}">
                    <img class="front" ng-src="http://dummyimage.com/128x96/000/fff.jpg&text=3"> 
                    <img class="back" ng-src="http://dummyimage.com/128x96/000/fff.jpg&text=5">
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.card-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 220px;
    height: 147px;
    -webkit-perspective: 800px;
    -moz-perspective: 800px;
    -ms-perspective: 800px;
    -o-perspective: 800px;
    perspective: 800px;
}

.card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 1s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
    transition: transform 1s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card img {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qgxmeddk/4/)

```
.card .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

you forgot to put  preserve-3d in back image

Comment: It's kind of weird as well that if you simply add **`background-color: initial;`** to **`.card img`**, it solves the problem as well. **[forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qju4kt5n/)**

Comment: Yup there are many solutions to a single problem .what matters is that which one clicked in your mind first